# Does a handle passed to unmanaged code need to be pinned?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I have an unmanaged function that I need to call which takes in as an argument a wait handle.  The unmanaged code signals this wait handle when appropriate to notify my code of some condition.  My question is, do I need to pin this wait handle in some way to prevent GC from moving the wait handle?

The (pseudo) code looks like:

```
using (var resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false))
{
    var iBuffer = Convert.ToUInt32(resetEvent.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle().ToInt32());
    // Pass iBuffer to unmanaged API function.  The unmanaged API passes in the wait handle as a ref uint.

    var handles = new[] {resetEvent, _cancellationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle};
    while(WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles) == 0)
    {
       // do stuff in response to resetEvent being signaled.
    }
}
```

I'm not passing the AutoResetEvent object (or even the 'SafeWaitHandle' from it) directly, but actually the DangerousGetHandle() returned.  I'm unclear if the 'Dangerous' handle returned really represents an unmanaged resource already and hence would not require any pinning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, No.

Pinning is needed to prevent managed memory from being moved. A handle on the other hand represents some operating system resource, and therefore does not need to be pinned.

You may still need to be carefull the handle is not saved by the unmanaged code, and ensure the handle is not release/invalidate/close/dispose while it is used by the unmanaged code.